# chdir(<directory>) doesn't change directory after exiting to shell

Tags: process, c, cd-command

I wanted to make a simple `C` program to change to my project directory. Its content is as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    chdir("/home/enedil/projects/algo");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with following command (`pro.c` is its file name):

```
gcc pro.c -o /usr/local/bin/pro
```

There were no errors nor warnings. But when I run it, it does **not** change directory. Why?

Comment: You could use an alias instead - `alias proj='cd ~/enedil/projects/algo'`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant oh, you meant `cd ~/projects/algo`? It is an idea!

Comment: This is by design!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your program does exactly what you tell it to do: it changes the working directory for **itself** to `/home/enedil/projects/algo`. But once it exits, the **shell's** working directory is restored.

I guess what you want to achieve is to change the working directory of the parent process, i.e. the shell, without resorting to a simple `cd`. There is [a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process), but as its author says: don't do it.

Comment: Nitpick, but the shell's working directory isn't restored, because it never changed. The shell is simply a process, just like the program is. Each program has it's own working directory.

Comment: @Patrick, true. Conceptually more accurate would be **your** working directory is restored, in that your process is "restored" (is active in the foreground).

Answer (score 6):

The current working directory is local to the process. So, what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

To do this for the shell, use the [`source`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18_01) command (aliased to `.`). It will run the application in the context of the current shell rather than creating a new shell context. This is how you can set environment variables as well. If you notice all of the startup scripts in `/etc/rc.d` or `/etc/init.d`, you will see lots of scripts that are included by other scripts with the command

```
. /etc/init.d/rcvars
```

The `.` causes the script `/etc/init.d/rcvars` so that anything it changes persists in the current environment.

Comment: You can't run a C program this way, only a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `CDPATH` environmental variable. As explained in `man bash`:

```
   CDPATH The search path for the cd command.  This is  a  colon-separated
          list  of  directories  in  which the shell looks for destination
          directories specified by the cd  command.   A  sample  value  is
          ".:~:/usr".
```

So, for example, you could add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
CDPATH=~/projects
```

You can now run `cd projects` from any directory and move to `~/projects`.